# How can I add Buy and Sell arrows with this condition?

Tags: pine-script

Please what is the syntax for adding a buy and sell arrow with conditions below. I am familiar with the famous crossover and crossunder. I want the buy arrow to print below bar whenever RSI is above 50 and sell arrow above bar whenever arrow is below 50.

(rsi15m < 50 ? color.red:color.green)

The code is pinescript version 5.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wish to do?
https://www.tradingview.com/x/yYjrxueI/

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)

rsi = ta.rsi(close, 14)

plotshape(rsi < 50 ? high : na,"RSI<50", shape.arrowdown, location.abovebar,color.red)

plotshape(rsi > 50 ? low : na,"RSI>50", shape.arrowup, location.belowbar,color.green)
```